# How to change format of field from epoh to date

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, text, kibana

I have a field in data file which is in epoch format.I want to change data in that field into date format. Is there any easy way?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JRZj8myVu1UHJ3jxZzzb8LSKKMicY0Qi

Comment: you can write a function to convert your epoh field to date and replace in your file

Comment: I can.But I want to know if there is any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the ingest [`date` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-processor.html) feature which will read your date fields containing an epoch value and transform them to the normal ISO8601 format:

First you can create the pipeline like this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/epoch-to-format
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "date": {
        "field": "arrival_timestamp",
        "target_field": "arrival_timestamp",
        "formats": [
          "UNIX_MS"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "field": "event_timestamp",
        "target_field": "event_timestamp",
        "formats": [
          "UNIX_MS"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when you ingest a document, you can specify the pipeline to use:

```
PUT test/doc/1?pipeline=epoch-to-format
{
   "event_timestamp": 1556843795341,
   "arrival_timestamp": 1556843798527,
   ...
}
```

And you'll end up with this document being indexed into ES:

```
GET test/doc/1
{
   "arrival_timestamp" : "2019-05-03T00:36:38.527Z",
   "event_timestamp" : "2019-05-03T00:36:35.341Z",
   ...
}
```

When ingesting with Python, you can specify the pipeline like this:

```
es.index(index='indexname', doc_type='typename', body="string", pipeline='epoch-to-format')
```

Comment: I am using python code to ingest documents.                         es.index(index='indexname', doc_type='typename', body="string") where should I include "?pipeline=epoch-to-format" thing in this.

Comment: ? it is fine if I don't give it a id.

Comment: I want to put data through request.post() method.Where should I include                    " pipeline='epoch-to-format' "?     see this link https://pypi.org/project/requests/0.5.1/

Comment: are we connected?